# Codigo em python usando biblioteca HMAC

Tags: python, criptografia, hash

Estou fazendo um trabalho sobre criptografia para a faculdade usando HMAC junto com SHA256, e gostaria de entender o que este código faz em cada linha, estou um pouco confuso.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import hashlib
import hmac
from math import ceil

hash_len = 32
def hmac_sha256(key, data):
    return hmac.new(key, data, hashlib.sha256).digest()

def hkdf(length, ikm, salt=b"", info=b""):
    prk = hmac_sha256(salt, ikm)
    t = b""
    okm = b""
    for i in range(ceil(length / hash_len)):
        t = hmac_sha256(prk, t + info + bytes([1+i]))
        okm += t
    return okm[:length]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora a resposta do @Marcelo Uchimura responda a questão, acho que não responde o para que serve o código, inclusive menciona que isto seria para mensagens, onde não é ponto.

---

O HKDF é um KDF usando HMAC, [há uma definição dele aqui](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/264.pdf). Bem, um KDF tem como entrada um dado "não tão aleatória" e uma outro dado, este que é uniformemente aleatório. Um bom exemplo de uso é quando uma chave é acordada via ECDH, já que a chave é "resposta matemática", portanto não é indistinguível de um dado completamente aleatório, dessa forma o uso de KDF é necessário. Da mesma forma, você pode querer ter várias chaves usando apenas uma única, assim o HKDF também pode ser usado, *mesmo que a chave necessite de *mais bytes* do que o valor original.*

---

O HKDF é dividido em duas parte, uma o extrator e outra o expansor. Este é o extrator:

```
prk = hmac_sha256(salt, ikm)
```

A ideia aqui é incluir o `salt` e o `ikm`. Presume que o `salt` é distinguível de um dado uniformemente aleatório, já o `ikm` talvez seja, mas não precisa ser.

Seu resultado, o `prk`, é um dado uniformemente aleatório, assumindo que o `hmac_sha256` seja um PRF seguro, *ou que ao menos a compressão do SHA256 seja um PRF.*

Depois disso temos o expansor, *que consume o `prk`*, ele está em:

```
for i in range(ceil(length / hash_len)):

    t = hmac_sha256(prk, t + info + bytes([1+i]))
```

Observe que o `prk` é usado como chave nesta etapa. Isso é, a chave gerada pelo extrator é usada no expansor. O expansor irá criar n bytes necessários, por isso existe o `range` para repetir o processo até que atinja a quantidade de bytes exigida.

Formalmente este processo é descrito como:

```
K(1) = HMAC(PRK, CTXinfo || 0),
K(i + 1) = HMAC(PRK, K(i) || CTXinfo || i), 1 ≤ i < t,
```

O `CTXinfo` é uma informação adicional, pode ser omitido. Então basicamente a entrada do HMAC é: o resultado anterior (se i > 1) concatenado com a informação adicionado e concatenado com o i, sendo `i` um único byte, sequencial.

No caso desta implementação, como está definido o `t = b""`, não haverá diferença entre a primeira ou última execução.

Por fim o `okm[:length]` irá apenas cortar a saída, já que a hash tem tamanho fixo (no caso do SHA-256), então se quiser valores não múltiplos de 256, por exemplo, não conseguirá sem truncar.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu estiver correto, é assim que funciona:

```
# Comentários na linha de cima à linha comentada.

import hashlib
import hmac
from math import ceil

# As palavras vão ter 32 bytes.
hash_len = 32

# Define um método que aplica SHA256 com a key e os data informados.
def hmac_sha256(key, data):
    return hmac.new(key, data, hashlib.sha256).digest()

# Cria um HMAC do tamanho length, com a chave ikm, o sal salt e uma informação, também usada para a criação do HMAC, info.
def hkdf(length, ikm, salt=b"", info=b""):

    # Gera uma chave preliminar com o salt e o ikm informados.
    prk = hmac_sha256(salt, ikm)

    # Declara um espaçador t.
    t = b""

    # Declara o HMAC final okm.
    okm = b""

    # Laço para gerar o HMAC; itera-se sobre um vetor [0..ceil(length / 32)]
    for i in range(ceil(length / hash_len)):
        # O espaçador guarda o resultado do algoritmo de hashing
        # a cada iteração, usando como base para tal a si próprio,
        # a info e um vetor de zeros de tamanho variável, apenas
        # como preenchedor (para que t não fique viciado).
        t = hmac_sha256(prk, t + info + bytes([1+i]))

        # Concatena t em okm
        okm += t

    # Recorta okm do tamanho length informado.
    return okm[:length]
```

Como o HMAC acompanha a mensagem assinada em todo o tempo da troca da mensagem, o fato de HMAC ser truncado não é significante, pois pode ser conferido a qualquer momento caso o receptor da mensagem tenha a mesma `length`, `ikm`, `salt` e `info` passadas como parâmetro de `hkdf()`, que também deve ser conhecido pelo lado receptor.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora consegui entender!